# Laravel Shopify Osiset: How do I use Osiset functions correctly?

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I've been dealing with the `Laravel/Osiset-Shopify` framework for some time and even after a long research there are things that I don't understand yet.

For example, if I want to fetch my webhooks, it is relatively cumbersome

`Auth::user()->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/2021-04/webhooks.json')['body']`

There is a function `getWebhooks()` under `\osiset\laravel-shopify\src\ShopifyApp\Services\ApiHelper.php` which I would much rather use.

I came across this [documentation](https://osiset.com/laravel-shopify/classes/Osiset.ShopifyApp.Services.ApiHelper.html) from Osiset, for which I don't know how to use it.

I tried to load the service `use Osiset\ShopifyApp\Services\ApiHelper;` and get the output data `dd(ApiHelper::getWebhooks([]));`. However, I get the error message `Non-static method Osiset\ShopifyApp\Services\ApiHelper::getWebhooks() cannot be called statically`.

Also

```
$foo = new ApiHelper;
dd( $foo->getWebhooks() );
```

did not lead to any result: `Call to a member function rest() on null`.

Can someone show me how to access Osiset's internal functions and use the documentation properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [documentation](https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki)

and for the webhooks.json, You can use this to get the results $userId will be the user's primary key.

```
 $shop = User::find($userId); 
 $method = 'GET';
 $url = '/admin/api/2021-04/webhooks.json';
 return  $shop->api()->rest($method, $url, []);
```